# Are functional languages superior to imperative in building neural networks?

Tags: functional-programming, neural-network

Neural networks are usually characterized by a huge amount of data and necessity to use parallel computing. Does it make functional languages more suitable for building neural networks?

Comment: This question has been closed as unsuitable for Stackoverflow.  I disagree, even if the phrasing of the question makes it sound unsuitable.  The generalized question is: Are there reasons in general, to think that functional or imperative programming is a better fit for neural networks.  Any answer would have an implicit "depends on the the details" qualifier, but there are general factors that are relevant, e.g.: How many nodes and links do you have, and how often will each node be updated?  Would a matrix representation make your networks easier or harder to understand?

Answer (score 3):

Not really. Functional languages usually make parallelization trivial if you stick to immutability (or more precisely avoid any kind of uncontrolled side effects). If you do not, then it's not really easier to make things parallel then in non functional languages.
In this case you have two options:

- use side effects, but in a localized fashion, so parallel threads have no business with each other: e.g. you evaluate a lot of NN-s, each of them can happen on it's own thread (using a thread pool with not much more threads than the number of CPU cores is a good idea).
- for non localized side effects you need to rely on synchronization or some other ways to control it. One such example is the computation model of actors (quite popular in functional language users, but also available for java, see http://akka.io/) which usually let you have your side effects within your actor, but the interaction of the actors has its strict rules. This will free you from the business of low level thread handling.

Another thing that you should consider is that it's not too difficult to have a moderately performant NN implementation, it's also not very complicated to have a purely functional one, but doing both at the same time can be a challenging task. So - unless you are experienced with functional languages - I think it's easier to write a parallelized NN in a non functional language, or at least in a non pure way.

Comment: That's a helpful answer, Sandor.  I prefer functional programming but have assumed that my application would be more efficient, more easily, with an imperative network.  You have confirmed my intuition, for my kind of application.  (It's an agent-based simulation with a 5000-node neural network in every agent.  Every node is updated on every iteration, so I don't think laziness would help (unless I don't understand laziness).  If I want parallelization, it will probably be most convenient to do that at the agent level.)